# Does there exist $f(z)$ s.t. all sigular points are $z=\mathrm{i}\ n$ and $f(z)$ can exponential decay in left and right half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist holomorphic function $f(z)$ such that all sigular points are  $z=\mathrm{i}\ n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(z)$ exponentially decays in left and right half planes?

This question comes from the [Matsubara summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsubara_frequency) where the weight function is chosen such that the weight function is chosen to control the convergence in left half plane or right half plane. So I wonder whether there exist a function which can control both sides and still have singular points in $z=\mathrm{i}\ n$?

Comment: What about $1/\sin(i\pi \cdot z)$?

Comment: @M.Winter Nice example! :)